# Extracting part of the string using strapplyc in R

Tags: r, string

I have the following sentence, sent:

```
> "#stance=iPhone : The next revolution of Apple"
```

And I would like to extract the stance.

After using

```
strapplyc(sent, "stance=(.*)", simplify = TRUE)
```

I obtained the following:

```
> "iPhone : The next revolution of Apple"
```

Anyone knows if there is a better way to just extract out the "iphone" in this case?

Comment: Maybe `sub("#stance=","","#stance=iPhone : The next revolution of Apple")` ?

Comment: You haven't specified the packages you are using here.

Comment: It's `library("gsubfn")`.

Comment: @Marta, I'm trying to lead the OP on how to correctly post a question on SO *sigh*. Also, you do realize that there is no need in that package here at all as shown above?

Comment: Yes, I know. But probably @Nana needs this package for something more complicated and she is just consistent. I think that it is better to help somebody in the world that he knows and experienced. But maybe I'm not right.

Answer (score 1):

Try this (add `:` in this regex):

```
strapplyc(sent, "stance=(.*) :", simplify = TRUE)
```

Comment: Thank you! It works now. May I ask what does "(.*) :" mean in R?

Comment: `"stance=(.*)"` means that you want to extract everything with starts with `stance=` and `.*` means everything till the end. If you add `:` than you say "extract everything between `stance=` and `:`".